# cant update DB with PDO/SQL it make fields blank

Tags: sql, database, pdo

My problem is that when i try to update my DB table (hold) it makes all fields blank.
im using three files a config to connect.This is the config.php file.

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='kv5772';

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=gade",$username,$password);

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Then there is a print page print.php. With a delete button. It works. But the edit dont.

```
<?php include "config.php" ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hold";?>
<table>      
  <tr>
    <td>hold</td>
    <td>leder</td> 
    <td>telefon</td>
    <td>mail</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){
    ?>

  <tr>
    <td><input name="hold" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo "{$row['hold']}";?>"/></td>
    <td><input name="leder" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo "{$row['leder']}";?>"/></td> 
    <td><input name="telefon" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo "{$row['telefon']}";?>"/></td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo "{$row['email']}";?>"/></td>
    <td>
        <form action="formupdatecode.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="edit" />
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
    <form action="slet.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="delete" />
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<?php
}

$db = null; 
?>
```

The edit button is connected to formupdatecode.php.

```
<?php include "config.php" ?>



<?php

$sql = "UPDATE hold SET hold = :hold, 
            leder = :leder, 
            telefon = :telefon,  
            email = :email   
            WHERE id = :id";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                    
$stmt->bindParam(':hold', $_POST['hold'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':leder', $_POST['leder'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':telefon', $_POST['telefon'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   


if($stmt->execute()){
echo "Successfully redigeret hold";
}// End of if profile is ok 
else{
print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); // if any error is there it will be posted
$msg=" Database problem, please contact site admin ";
}


?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your input fields be inside the form?

Comment: oh my god im stupid thx

Comment: Added a short answer so that the question doesn't remain un-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code has a problem with the location of the input tags.

Your edit/input fields are located outside the form and will not be included in the POST back to the server.